# JSON manipulation in scala

Tags: json, scala

I have a huge flat json string which has some 1000+ fields. I want to restructure the json into a nested/hierarchical structure based on certain business logic without doing a lot of object-to-json or json-to-object conversions, so that the performance will not get affected.

What are the ways to achieve this in scala?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make it an object in scala however you desire(Complexity) and then do something like a `Stringify` to convert it to JSON and then you can parse it back to scale similarly...

Comment: This link [HERE](http://www.justjson.com/2016/05/convert-scala-object-tofrom-json-string.html) would help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a look into JSON transformers provided by play-json library. It allows you to manipulate json (moving fields, creating nested objects) without doing any object mapping.

Check this out : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonTransformers